# How to perform edit action in ASP.net Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How to perform edit action in ASP.net Core? I have the following code for product detail view action i need help on creating action for edit page

//IProduct interface

```
namespace Proj.Core.App.Common.Product
{    public interface IProductService
    {
        Task<IList<ProductDTO>> GetProducts();
    }
}
```

//Product Controller

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    { 
    public IProductService ProductService { get; }
    public ProductController(IProductService ProductService)
        {
            ProductService = ProductService;
        }    
//DetailAction    
       [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
        {
            var ProductList= (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();        
            var project = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
            @ViewBag.Product_Code = product.productCode;
            @ViewBag.Product_Name = product.productName;      

            return View();
        }
     }
```

how can i create action for Edit page action?

Comment: Your question is missing too much information for a proper answer.

Comment: Doesn't visual studio scaffold all of this for you?

Answer (score 3):

I left a comment that the question really needs more information to answer properly. However, maybe the stuff below might help to get you started.

Here is an implementation using the methods you already have.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var productList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();

    var product = productList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

This is what typical entity framework implementation looks like. Extract what information you can from it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(applications);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(product);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductExists(product.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(applications);
}

private bool ProductExists(int id)
{
    return _context.Products.Any(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Just would like to point out that getting the full list of products, then searching the result for the individual item is less efficient, that simply creating a FindById method in the service.

Comment: Thank you Matt, how can I add “save” button in a view to save the changes in the database

Answer (score 0):

```
    //DetailAction    
    [HttpPut()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Product model)
    {
        ..call your service or ...
        return View();
    }
```